# mysql default value

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I currently have a field in my database title attributes. The following were added as defaults:

```
{"ag_type": [ "ag:adult40s", "ag:teen", "ag:senior"], "gender_type": "unisex"}
```

and in my rails app, I have these attributes set up as check boxes in the view, and all default to "checked". However I need to add a few more attributes as default so it looks as so:

```
{"ag_type": [ "ag:adult20s", "ag:adult30s", "ag:adult40s", "ag:teen", "ag:senior"], "gender_type": "unisex"}
```

When I add these values as defaults, they do now change the defaults for each row in the database, however when i check the structure they are added as defaults. How can I change the defaults for each record in the database (About 40,000 records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
console: rails g migration SetDefaultValuesForMyField
```

which will create a empty migration in db/migrate

Inside the migration you could do:

```
class SetDefaultValuesForMyField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :table, :ag_type, :text, :default =>  [ "ag:adult40s", "ag:teen", "ag:senior"]
    Table.update_all ["ag_type= ?", [ "ag:adult40s", "ag:teen", "ag:senior"]]
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

[More on migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables)